# segue after login with Facebook Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to push another view after login succesfully login with facebook.But I couldn't realize how can I do that.Can anybody Help me ?

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard?

Comment: yes,I'am using storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you complete your login with facebook, generally, you will have two ways to open some other view controller

- If you have configured a segue, use following code

  ```
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self)
  ```
- If you want to initialize a viewController using StoryBoardId, use following code

  ```
  let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardID") as UIViewController 
  self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  ```

Here's Update for swift 3, Xcode 8:

To initialize a viewController using StoryBoardId:

```
let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryBoardId") as UIViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Make sure you are doing the above in Main Thread.

Comment: Updated code for swift 2 and Xcode 7 :
let viewController =  self.storyboard!
                .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second_view") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)     }

Answer (score 0):

Set up your second view by adding a Storyboard ID to it in the Identity Inspector. Then call it this way:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardID", bundle: nil)
let secondView =  storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourStoryBoardID") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(secondView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: am I use this in prepareforsegue ? And I have 1 storyboard.I called that main.storyboard in this storyboard I have 2 view controller one of them is login view other is profile view who come after success login process

Comment: Have you set up the Storyboard ID yet?